# Jenkins CI deploy NodeJS project

Tags: linux, node.js, jenkins

Всем привет! Возникла проблема с Jenkins CI, собственно есть сервер на Амазоне с Linux-ом на нём установлен Jenkins CI. Сам дженкинс тянет код с github при commit и выполняет инструкции которые находятся в файле Jenkinsfile. Содержимое файла:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
   agent any
    stages {
        stage('Install') {
            steps {
                echo 'Install...'
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Stop all') {
            steps {
                echo 'Stop all...'
                sh 'forever stopall'
            }
        }
         stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
                sh 'BUILD_ID=dontKillMe forever start app.js'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно что бы при выполнении Deploy процесс не убивался дженкинсом и продолжал работать что бы сайт был поднят, но этого не происходи так как по умолчанию он убивается. Было найдено решение использовать

> BUILD_ID=dontKillMe forever start app.js

но это так же не помогло. В отчёте дженкинса всё в порядке лог на пункте deploy:

```
[Node_Message] Running shell script
+ BUILD_ID=dontKillMe forever start app.js
[33mwarn[39m:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
[33mwarn[39m:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
[32minfo[39m:    Forever processing file: [90mapp.js[39m
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это именно дженкинс прибивает процесс?

Comment: @etki Не уверен если честно, просто уже не знаю куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это баг [JENKINS-46481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46481). На текущий момент BUILD_ID=dontKillMe не работает коректно под всеми ОС.
Как выход можно сделать сервис и запускать его через Jenkins.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.